# I'm trying to use multiplot to combine plot and splot but x,y labels seem to be shifted

Tags: gnuplot

```
set xrange [-2:2]
set yrange [-2:2]

set xlabel 'X'
set ylabel 'Y'

set samples 300
set isosamples 300


set lmargin screen 0.1
set rmargin screen 0.9
set tmargin screen 0.9
set bmargin screen 0.1

set multiplot

set pm3d map
set palette grey
unset colorbox 
splot x**2+y**2 < 1 ? 0:0.2
unset pm3d

plot sin(x) lc 0
```

This code displays the problem - different positionning of x/y labels by splot, plot.

[image: splot (pm3d map) and plot inside multiplot. x/y labels shifted]

Answer (score 0):

Although you have the margins identical for both plots for some reason (which I don't know) the labels are not at identical positions. However, since the label values are identical anyway, no need for trying to plot the second labels on top of the first ones. Simply skip all labels and tics of the second plot.

**Code:**

```
### remove shifted tics in multiplot
reset session

set xrange [-2:2]
set yrange [-2:2]

set xlabel 'X'
set ylabel 'Y'

set samples 300
set isosamples 300

set lmargin screen 0.1
set rmargin screen 0.9
set tmargin screen 0.9
set bmargin screen 0.15

set multiplot
    set pm3d map
    set palette grey
    unset colorbox 
    splot x**2+y**2 < 1 ? 0:0.2
    unset pm3d

    unset xlabel
    unset ylabel
    unset xtics
    unset ytics

    plot sin(x) lc 0
unset multiplot
### end of code
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Yes, that's what I have to do for now. Identical margins scale and place plot frame  perfectly but labels and tics are shifted. Looks like some offsets differ or is it a  bug ?

Comment: Yes, my guess would be that these are some differences in default offsets between plot and splot.

Answer (score 0):

It is quite possible that you can create your composite plot entirely with `splot` and therefore do not need to use multiplot, bypassing the whole issue.  I realize that the example you give may be over-simplified but as it stands the plot can be created by

```
set xrange [-2:2]
set yrange [-2:2]
set trange [-2:2]

set xlabel 'X'
set ylabel 'Y'

set samples 300
set isosamples 300

set view map
set pm3d at b
set palette grey
unset colorbox 

splot x**2+y**2 < 1 ? 0:0.2 with pm3d, \
      '+' using 1:(sin($1)):(0) with lines lc "blue" lw 3
```

[image]

Comment: Yes,it's an interesting solution. Actually, I need to plot 2D areas and various curves, some of which can only be defined parametrically. Besides, cairolatex terminal I use conflicts with '$1' parameters. But these are solved by 

splot   A(x,y) w pm3d , \
        '+' u 1:(F(column(1))):(0) w l lc 'red' ,\
        '+' u (PX(column(1))):(PY(column(1))):(1) w l lc 'blue'

Comment: So far as I know parametric mode plots can always be replaced by a equivalent explicit form: `plot '+' using (fx($1)):(fy($1))`.  Yes you can use `column(1)` rather than `$1`.    The converse trick might also be possible: Convert the 3D projection to a purely 2D form so you can mix it with arbitrary 2D plot styles to compose the same figure entirely using a single `plot` command.

Answer (score 0):

With gnuplot 5.2.8, the figure can be created with just one `plot` command:

```
pl [-2:2][-2:2] sample [0:2*pi] "+" us (cos(x)):(sin(x)) with filledcurve, sin(x)
```

[image]

Thus `splot` and `multiplot` are not needed here.

`sample` is needed to redefine the parameter range (only in case of first plot argument).
A documentation is here: https://github.com/gnuplot/gnuplot/blob/4a7a11e6b528ea362c943cf632fd21a518b15c54/docs/gnuplot.doc#L7856

PS: As you see it also works without `$1` for your `cairolatex` terminal.